# Is awaitTxConfirmed mandatory?

Tags: plutus

I am running into timing issues, and am considering leaving out `awaitTxConfirmed`.
Is that wise?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may broadcast transactions in *fire and forget* manner. If the fact whether it got into a block or not is not important to you, skipping  `awaitTxConfirmed` is not a bad idea.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't care whether a transaction has not been added to the ledger, then you can skip `awaitTxConfirmed`. But in that case, do you need to use blockchain in the first place?

What are the timing issues? Why do you have timing issues? What are you trying to accomplish? Do you need confirmation that a transaction has been added to the ledger? What if it hasn't and you're assuming the transaction has been confirmed and you act upon a false assumption?

There's not enough information to give you an answer, but these questions might help you in coming up with your own answer.